# Online quiz examination DB schema structure tables relationship using laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, database-relations

I am working with online quiz examination project in Laravel. I have planned for a db structure with almost possibilities, but looking for more optimized way.

Requirement: 
Need to add question. Before adding question I need the following, for which standard, for which class, for which subject, for which chapter, for which topic this question belongs to.

So this is my plan:

Add Class - > this has a form and a table to add classes(1st std, 2nd std, 3rd std ... so on)

Add Subject -> this has a form and a table (Maths english , chemistry, english)

Add Chapters-> has a form and table, for specific subject those chapters belong to (one to many relationship one subject many chapters)

add Topics -> this has a form and table, for specific chapter these topics belongs to (one to many relationship. one chapter can have many topics)

Now I need to add the question. I have a question form where the form has controls such as asking about which class, which subject, which chapter, which topic, which level.

my `EduationStandardtable` with fields

```
id  standard_name
1   CBSE
2   ICSE
3   Matriculation
4   State board
```

my `classDetailstable` with fields

```
id  class_name
1   5th std
2   6th std
3   7th std
```

my `SubjectDetails table` with fields

```
id  sub_name
1   english
2   maths
3   physics
```

my `ChapterDetails table` with fields

```
id  subject_id      ChapterName
1   1               Matrices
2   1               Integration
3   1               Differentiation
4   3               Electrostatics
5   3               Tranformation
6   3               Electricity
```

my `TopicDetails table` with fields

```
id  chapter_id          Topic_id
1   1              Inverse of a Non-Singular
2   1             Elementary Transformations of a Matrix
3   1           Solving System of Linear Equations
4   4           Role of electrostatic
5   4           Electric flux
6   4           Polaraisation
```

So I planned to have my question table like this,

```
id
education_standard_id(fk)
class_id   (fk)
subject_id (fk)
chapter_id (fk)
topic_id (fk)
level (easy,medium,hard)
question_number
question_description
question_image(optional)
optionA:
optionA_image:(optional)
optionB:
optionB_image:(optional)
optionC:
optionC_image:(optional)
optionD:
optionD_image:(optional)
correctanswer
explanation
explanation_image (optional)
explanation_pdf (optional)
explanation-video(optional)
```

Is this enough? How else can I optimise this.

Here, class and subject are related, means a single class can have many subjects and single subject can have many classes.

a subject can have many chapters, so one to many.
a chapter can have many topics, so one to many.

so totally 5 forms `adding-class, adding-subject, adding-chapter, adding-topic, adding-question`

totally five tables `class-table, subject-table, chapter -table, topic-table, question-table`

One of my friends in another forum suggested like this

```
classes ( id, name ) //slug or others if you want
subjects (id, name ) // slug or others if you want
chapters(id, name, subject_id)  // this belongs to a subject so it's a "child"
topics (id, name, chapter_id) // topic is child of chapter
class_topic (id, class_id, topic_id) // this is the pivot table because each class studies a topic...

Example
$class_5 = ClassObject::find(5);
$topics = $class_5->topics()->get();

// iterate and display topic->name
```

My confusion is the forms. I am using 5 forms for adding those. Is this right? How else can I reduce the forms. I think all the tables are needed. But whether those are right?

Comment: Your question is a bit convoluted, mainly because it mixes two questions: your datastructure and how to build your forms. Although you would have to repeat some background information, I'd suggest to split these into 2 questions. An answer to "Do I need 5 forms to enter master data into 5 tables?" is independent from the answer to "Should I change my datastructure (specifically the questions-table)" (without mentioning forms). You should also elaborate on the "class_topic" suggested by your friend, since it differs from your structure above (e.g. "Do I need this to do <my requirements>").

Comment: To critique a schema, I request to see the queries to be run.

Comment: i have posted the question in another thread. kindly suggest guys..